# If $a+b=1$ where $a,b\in\Bbb R^+$ then prove that $a^ab^b+b^aa^b\le1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a+b=1$ such that $a$ and $b$ are **positive real numbers**, then prove $$a^a b^b+b^a a^b\le1$$

I tried applying Arithmetic and Geometric mean but it doesn't work. I also tried to equate the given equation with $a^0$( which would be equal to $1$), but, as it turns out, that doesn't work either

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: in what context?

Comment: To do this yourself of course

Comment: I tried applying Arithematic and Geometric mean but it does'nt work. I also tried to equate the given equation with a^0( which would be equal to 1), but, as it turns out, that does'nt work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By AM-GM $a^ab^b+a^bb^a\leq a\cdot a+b\cdot b+b\cdot a+a\cdot b=1$.

Comment: but you just used the "to Prove" side, actually this is a problem I found while giving a competitive exam and the contestant is not allowed to use the given inequality which we have to prove in order to actually solve the problem

Comment: @Lucifer I used AM-GM: If $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n=1$, where $\alpha_i>0$ and $x_i>0$ so $\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+...+\alpha_nx_n\geq x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}...a_n^{\alpha_n}$

Comment: Got it. Also, can I ask you something off topic?

Comment: Michael Rozenberg, I am new to this site, so I do'nt know much of the rules. So, can you tell me if posting questions on pure geometry is allowed? I mean, I've not seen any questions on geometry as of now, so, is it allowed

Comment: @Lucifer Yes you can.